# inputRange not working with Reanimated 3 after Upgrading from Reanimated 2

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am experiencing a problem with Reanimated 3. I don't see the change happening in real-time when I change a value. The change is only visible after I release the button. This issue started occurring after updating from Reanimated 2 to Reanimated 3. Could someone please assist me with this?"

here is the code

```
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useAnimatedProps,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  runOnJS,
  useDerivedValue,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

```
  const AnimatedTextInput = Animated.createAnimatedComponent<any>(TextInput);
  const animatedText = useDerivedValue(
    () =>
      `${
        Math.round((xKnob.value / MAXWIDTH) * (props.distance / props.steps)) *
        props.steps
      }`,
  );
```

```
  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps<any>(() => {
    return {
      text: animatedText.value,
    };
  });
```

```
   <AnimatedTextInput
            defaultValue={'0'}
            editable={false}
            animatedProps={animatedProps}
          />
```

I upgraded my project from Reanimated 2 to Reanimated 3, expecting a seamless transition and improved performance. However, I've encountered an issue where value changes are not reflected in real time during interactions. For instance, when I modify a value through a button press, I expect the UI to update immediately to reflect this change. Instead, the update only occurs after I release the button, which is not the desired behavior. This issue was not present in Reanimated 2, and it seems to have been introduced with the upgrade to Reanimated 3. I'm looking for guidance or solutions to ensure real-time updates as values change.

Answer (score 0):

If inputRange isn't working with Reanimated 3 after upgrading from Reanimated 2, you can try these steps:

- Rebuild your app
- Install [react-native-reanimated alpha](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started) as a dependency in your project
- Add Reanimated's babel plugin to your babel.config.js

Upgrading from Reanimated 2 to 3 can cause things to break. For example, a sophisticated timeline component may break in many ways.

- Reanimated 2 doesn't work with the Chrome debugger
- Expo doesn't fully support the new architecture yet

**Solution 2**

React Native `Animatable` Text is a library that allows you to animate text in React Native. It is a fork of React Native's Animated component that supports more animation options.

To use **React Native Animatable Text**, you first need to install it:

> npm install react-native-animateable-text

Once installed, you can import it into your project:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, Text } from 'react-native';
import AnimatableText from 'react-native-animateable-text';
```

Then, you can create an `AnimatableText` component and pass in the text that you want to animate:

```
const AnimatedTextExample = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Hello, world!');

  return (
    <AnimatableText
      animation="fadeIn"
      duration={1000}
      style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
      {text}
    </AnimatableText>
  );
};
```

Comment: I use this library "react-native-animateable-text" and it works now.

thank you for your reply

Comment: Can I add this plugin to my answer for more improvement?